# Networking an external hard drive

Tags: networking, external-hard-drive

Hi I want to buy an external hard drive for my macbook but I was wondering if it is possible to connect my external hard drive to a network. the external hard drive is: SEAGATE BACKUP PLUS DESKTOP 4TB FOR MAC THUNDERBOLT and there are two options which might help:

1- we have a server, is it possible that I connect my external hard drive through my own macbook to the server that others could have access to it?

2- I might be able to construct a network and give access to the other computers to store their data on my external hard drive.

Thanks

Comment: I would be shocked if you cannot set a drive connected to your computer as a shared network drive. Because your external drive is Thunderbolt the normal oepration of simply hooking it up to a router won't work. There are very few NAS Thunderbolt devices currently ( I would be shocked if any even exist ).  So connected it to the Server, set it up as a network drive, and see if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No.  You can not connect it through your Macbook to the server for others to access.  You have to directly connect it to your server and set it up as shared drive or shared folder.  Then others can access it through the server but it would independent of your Macbook.
2. Yes, you can construct a network but if you already have an internal network (say WiFi) then you already have one.  The drive does not appear to natively have ethernet capability so you would have to connect it to a device that does (server) and share it out.

Comment: If this is the correct solution for you please mark it the answer so everyone else knows this is what solved your problem.  Thanks!